# C++ Halting std::system command and returning to main() while said std::system command is running

Tags: c++, while-loop

So I am making a fake hacking hub, and I have this piece of code within it:

```
void tree() {
    std::system("cls"); // clears the screen
    while (not(GetKeyState(VK_BACK) & 0x8000)) { //
        std::system("tree C:\\"); // prints out the directory tree of the C: drive
    }
}
```

I want to halt execution of the C: drive tree command and return to the mainline WITHOUT having for the user to use the CTRL+C command, as this would stop the entire program from executing further.

Comment: not sure if I understand the code corrrectly. Do you really want to call `tree` repedeatly, or do you want to call it once and interrupt it when the user presses some key?

Comment: Please, don't *ever* use `system()`. It is a security *nightmare*.

Comment: Just buffer the whole output of `tree` and replay it while also watching for button presses.

Comment: You can use the `std::filesystem` to recursively traverse a given folder.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, I want it to loop, because I know that eventually the C:\ drive will run out of directories, but I also want it to be able to be interrupted when the user presses the backspace key so they can go back to the main terminal hub I created.

Comment: @Zimano How do I do that?

Comment: @AzGames You should realize that a system call only has a few (very restrictive) things you can do 'externally' with it (e.g. when calling it from another program) - besides, `tree` is a long running process, it's not one-shot like getting the operating system version or whatever. That program is just "running' - you can't 'tell' it to do anything; you can only read its output as it comes. That's why the only answer suggests reimplementing tree's functionality, because `tree` doesn't give you the interface that you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. As far as your program is concerned, a call to `std::system` is a single operation.

What you can do is *reimplement* what `tree C:\` does, but also listen for backspaces to cancel that.

Comment: Well, how would I do that?